# Reduce width of text while maintaining its alignment

Tags: html, css

I have text in the `<p>` tag.

My css for the `<p>` tag is as follows:

```
p {
max-width:1000px;
text-align:center;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}
```

So as you can see, I have centered the text and I have made so as the max width is not from one side of my screen to the other, which is how it currently is.

How can I fix this? I dont know what other styles to put.

Comment: Since you're setting a width, just use `margin:0 auto`. http://jsfiddle.net/yczr3/

Comment: Do you mean that setting a width like this is bad practice?

Comment: Also, it works perfectly. You can post an answer for me to accept if you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Just do this :**

```
p {
max-width:1000px;
margin: 0 auto;
text-align:center;
font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, "AppleGothic", sans-serif;
}
```

Margin auto will automatically arrange or adjust your text value or whatever content it's there.

It should work now..:)